# Amazon AWS where in better to store image plus data?

Tags: java, android, amazon-web-services

I have android application, which needs to store somewhere object which contains user uploaded image + description of image. May be later additional data will be added.

Which service is better to use to store such information? Is it efficient to store such objects in Amazon SimpleDB or it is better to store images in storage and save link to picture in DB?

Answer (score 4):

You should store the images in [Amazon S3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/) and then store a link to these images in your database.